# How can I reuse the same piece of HTML/CSS across multiple files?

Tags: html, css

I have many files with overlapping HTML/CSS (e.g nav bar, contact info). Is there a way for me to store these codes so that if I need to make changes, I only have to edit the one file instead of going through all my files? I've seen people use JavaScript, but I've only seen it applied to HTML, not HTML AND CSS.

Here's my CSS for contact info, for example:

```
 .fa-envelope {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
} 
 .fa-envelope:hover {
   color: #8790ff;
   transition: 1s;
 }
 .fa-linkedin-in {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
 } 
.fa-linkedin-in:hover {
   color: #8790ff;
   transition: 1s;
 }
.fa-github {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
} 
.fa-github:hover {
   color: #8790ff;
   transition: 1s;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
   .fa-envelope {
       padding-top: 50px;
       padding-bottom: 50px;
       padding-right: 25px;
       font-size: 20px;
   }
  .fa-linkedin-in {
       padding: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
       font-size: 20px;
  } 
  .fa-github {
       padding: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
       font-size: 20px;
  } 
}   
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 999px) {
   .fa-envelope {
       padding-top: 50px;
       padding-bottom: 50px;
       padding-right: 25px;
       font-size: 25px;
   }
   .fa-linkedin-in {
       padding: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
       font-size: 25px;
   } 
   .fa-github {
       padding-top: 50px;
       padding-bottom: 50px;
       padding-left: 25px;
       font-size: 25px;
   } 
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
   .fa-envelope {
       padding-top: 50px;
       padding-bottom: 50px;
       padding-right: 25px;
       font-size: 30px;
   }
   .fa-linkedin-in {
       padding: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
       font-size: 30px;
   } 
   .fa-github {
       padding: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
       font-size: 30px;
   } 
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
   .fa-envelope {
       padding-top: 50px;
       padding-bottom: 50px;
       padding-right: 25px;
       font-size: 30px;
   }
   .fa-linkedin-in {
       padding: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
       font-size: 30px;
   } 
   .fa-github {
       padding: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
       font-size: 30px;
   } 
 }
```

HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3fdadcecb8.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div align = "center">
    <a href = "mailto: angela.haiqi@gmail.com" class = "fas fa-envelope"></a>
    <a href = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/angela-liu-8a281716a/" class = "fab fa-linkedin- 
    in"></a>
    <a href = "https://github.com/angelahaiqi" class = "fab fa-github"></a>
</div>
</body>
```

I'd want the contact info to be on the bottom of every page. How would I import this?

Comment: To include the same CSS, save your CSS in a plain text file and name it with `.css` extension. Then include it via `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='your/css/url.css'>`. But as for including the same HTML, that is a different conversation. That requires a server side language such as PHP, OR including it in a javascript file and writing it to the HTML on page load.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "include" HTML documents in other HTML documents using HTML.

For XHTML, there's techically XInclude, but I doubt any browser supports it for more than testing purpose since heavy usage of XML never became popular on the web.

This means: you're stuck with using server-side mechanisms to assemble your document from parts before sending it to the client. It's somehow outside the scope of a single quesiton on SO to name every possible way there is, but some examples might include:

- specific web-server specific mechanisms such as Apache's SSI (or similar modules for other webservers)
- server side scripting languages such as NodeJS, PHP or ASP
- template engines.

Alternatively you can use client side Javascript and asynchronous background requests (AJAX) to load the additional document and attach it to your DOM. You can also load CSS this way - or just include the CSS right away with a `<link>` tag.

Comment: true, and two more to add, iframes and javascript (get html via ajax + append)

Comment: Thank you! Which method would you recommend for a beginner?

Comment: That completely depends on your knowledge of programming languages and your server infrastructure. If you have access to PHP, then includes are an easy thing to learn.  If you have access to your webserver configuration and know the basics about the webserver software you use and how to configure it, server side includes are a fast and easy option, though not very versatile. If neither and you already know javascript, then go for the AJAX solution. If you don't know wnything about any of that, then either learn Javascript and/or nodeJS (learning PHP from nowadays is not sometihng I recommend)

Comment: (Note that there are likely a lot of other opinions on this subject, and the above is simply my point of view, not a fact-based answer)

Answer (score 2):

Well, in case of CSS, you may simply include it on all the pages you wish (using for instance `<link>` tag).

HTML case is kind of harder. What you are looking for is commonly referred to as "templating".
There's no (or at least, I never heard of) native way to create HTML templates.

Said this, you got 3 good & fairly common options:

1. If your site has any backend, you should be able create HTML templates using backend language of your choice (for example, [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)). This way you could split your HTML into pieces commonly called "partials".
2. You can construct an SPA application using something like [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) or [Angular](https://angular.io/). This way you could split your HTML into pieces called "components".
3. You could also generate a static website with static website generator like [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/), [Next](https://nextjs.org/) or [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/). This way of development is very similar to point 2.

Comment: Your answer made me aware that obviously one needs to use `link` and not `style` to include the CSS :-D Fixed that as well in my answer, but thanks for that!

Comment: @JohannesH. Glad it helped someone :)

Answer (score 1):

The link tag adds a link to the stylesheet. You just need to create a css file with that css in it.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="url_of_stylesheet" hreflang="en>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP for that it's much easier to include one file into other files with PHP that with plain HTML.
**Solutions**

1. **With PHP**

```
 <?php
   include('filename.php');
 ?>
```

2. **Writing your code in JS and including the file where you want**

   `<script src="file_name.js"></script>`

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're suggestion PHP out of all the possible server side languages?

ALso, It's not only easier than with HTML, it's impossible with pure HTML.

Comment: specifically, PHP is  much easier to switch to from HTML,
it's impossible with pure HTML but can be made possible with JS or Jquery by modifying page head contents.